# getting html instead of csv data using url link via python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to download a csv file from a salesforce report using python 3.7. I know one can use the API but unfortunately I do not have access to the API at the moment.

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://site.salesforce.com/00O1H000008Fg49?csv=1&exp=1&enc=UTF-8&isdtp=p1")
data.head()
```

and I get the following result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
0   <html>
1   <head>
2   <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
3   <script src="/jslibrary/1644529820240/ui-sfdc-...
4   <script>
```

How can I get the csv data instead of the HTML? when I paste the URL in a browser, the csv file is automatically downloaded and when I open the file, the data is there. How can I get the data in a pandas dataframe using the url link?

Comment: You are not authenticated.

Comment: oh wow. ok. Makes sense. any tip on how to do that? should I use Requests instead?

Comment: No, you will need to use their API. You could use Selenium to automate the login process, but it is quite slow.